# Send data from input to custom.js and make calculations on the basis of input in custom.js file

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Send data from input to custom.js and make calculations on the basis of  input in custom.js file & send value of sum from custom.js to create.blade.js

create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">                           
<label for="amount_received">Amount Received</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="p_amount_received" 
id="p_amount_received" oninput="myfunction()" placeholder="Enter Amount 
Received" required="">  
</div>
```

get p_amount_received in custom.js by id

custom.js

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("p_amount.received").value;
  var sum=x+10;
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<p></p>
```

how i get back sum in

create.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the custom.js using script tag in header or alike in create.blade.php and use onchange even to call the myFunction like,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="p_amount_received" 
id="p_amount_received" onChange="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter Amount 
Received" required="">
<label id='p_sum_display'>Sum</label>
<input type="hidden"  name="p_sum" id="p_sum" >
```

create sum as input for submitting to server and sum as display label for ui display and populate values  in through myFunctions like,

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("p_amount_received").value;
  var sum=x+10;
  document.getElementById("p_sum").value = sum  //for submit to server
  document.getElementById("p_sum_display").innerHTML = sum // to display to user on ui
}
```